# SQL join condition for 2 tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Do you know how to display only the lines in table for same ID where col3 is not 'X'?

table 1 :

```
    ID | col1 | col2 |   
     ---+-----+-----+   
    1 | 0     | 0    |    
    1 | D     | C    |    
    1 | D     | C    |    
    2 | 0     | 0    |    
    2 | D     | C    |    
    2 | D     | C    |   
    3 | D     | C    |   
    3 | D     | C    |   
    3 | D     | C    |
```

table 2 :

```
     ID | col1 | col2 | col3
     ---+------+------+-----
      1 | 0    | 0    | X
      1 | D    | C    | null
      1 | D    | C    | null
      2 | 0    | 0    | null
      2 | D    | C    | null
      2 | D    | C    | null
```

e.g., from the two tables above, it should display as result :

```
    ID | col1 | col2 | 
     ---+------+------+
      2 | 0    | 0    | 
      2 | D    | C    | 
      2 | D    | C    | 
      3 | D    | C    | 
      3 | D    | C    | 
      3 | D    | C    |
```

ID 2 (as all the col3 are null) and ID 3 (cause it's in table 1 but not in table 2 so it's like it's null, or it's like it doesn't have any col3=X)

It should work for all ID with some many line by ID and only the same ID with all line having null or not existing in table 2 but in table 1 only.

here is what i tried :

```
    select 
    T.id, T2.col1, T2.col2
    from table1 T 
    inner JOIN table2 T2 on T.ID=T2.ID
    where Cond1
    and T.ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT T2.ID FROM table2 T2 
    WHERE T.ID=T2.ID 
    AND T2.COL3='X') it displays only half of what i want :  ID | col1 | col2 | 
 ---+------+------+
  2 | 0    | 0    | 
  2 | D    | C    | 
  2 | D    | C    |
```

i need to have also in plus of ID=2 the ID=3 too :

```
3 | D    | C    | 
  3 | D    | C    | 
  3 | D    | C    |
```

thanks

Comment: show your code  ..

Comment: sorry, i did add the code and more explanation ,thanks in advance for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.col3 = 'X'
                 );
```

Comment: thanks, but it doens work in my case and i use it in the where, please check my code : 
select 
    T.id, T2.col1, T2.col2
    from table1 T 
    inner JOIN table2 T2 on T.ID=T2.ID
    where Cond1
    and T.ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT T2.ID FROM table2 T2 
    WHERE T.ID=T2.ID 
    AND T2.COL3='X')

Comment: @mids34 . . . The code in your comment is not the code in my answer.

Comment: i tried this : 
select T.id, T2.col1, T2.col2 
from table1 T 
inner JOIN table2 T2 on T.ID=T2.ID 
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.col3 = 'X'
                 )
and COND1
AND COND2;

Still diplaying only id from mytable2 having null and not the one in table 1 which are not in table2

Comment: Dear @Gordon Linoff, I tried unfortunatly i stil have the data lines only from table 2 having null (which is correct, ID=2 in my example) but not the line existing in table 1 and not 2 :( (ID=3 in my example) 
`select T1.* from T1 
inner join (tried with left too) 
table2 T2 on T1.ID=T2.ID) 
Where cond1 and cond2 and cond3 and 
not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.col3 = 'X' ); `
please advice,
Thanks in advance

Comment: @mids34 . . . Hint:  There is no `join` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use inner join on the distinct select where col3!='X'

```
select * from table1 
inner  join (
select distinct id from table2 
where col3 !='X' 
) t on t.id = table1.id
```